# Sorting csv data

Tags: python, csv

The ask is to sort and save a csv file in a new csv file. With the code below(below1), I seem to get the result when I open the new csv file. However, when I run the code on the homework interface, it prints out wrong (below2). Can anyone identify why it doesn't work? I have the correct solution to the ask as well (below3). I don't understand why mine doesn't work.

Below1:

```
import csv
def sort_records(csv_filename, new_filename):
    file = open(csv_filename)
    lines = file.readlines()
    newfile = open(new_filename, "w")
    header = lines[0]
    newfile.write(header)
    lines.remove(header)
    lines.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    for item in lines:
        newfile.write(item)
    file.close()
    newfile.close()
```

Below2:

city/month,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr
Brisbane,31.3,40.2,37.9,29
Darwin,34,34,33.2,34.5Melbourne,41.2,35.5,37.4,29.3

Below3:

```
import csv
def sort_records(csv_filename, new_filename):
    csv_file = open(csv_filename)
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    header = next(reader)
    data2d = list(reader)
    data2d.sort()
    csv_file.close()
    new_file = open(new_filename, "w")
    writer = csv.writer(new_file)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(data2d)
    new_file.close()
```

The original csv file:

city/month,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec
Melbourne,41.2,35.5,37.4,29.3,23.9,16.8,18.2,25.7,22.3,33.5,36.9,41.1
Brisbane,31.3,40.2,37.9,29,30,26.7,26.7,28.8,31.2,34.1,31.1,31.2
Darwin,34,34,33.2,34.5,34.8,33.9,32,34.3,36.1,35.4,37,35.5
Perth,41.9,41.5,42.4,36,26.9,24.5,23.8,24.3,27.6,30.7,39.8,44.2
Adelaide,42.1,38.1,39.7,33.5,26.3,16.5,21.4,30.4,30.2,34.9,37.1,42.2
Canberra,35.8,29.6,35.1,26.5,22.4,15.3,15.7,21.9,22.1,30.8,33.4,35
Hobart,35.5,34.1,30.7,26,20.9,15.1,17.5,21.7,20.9,24.2,30.1,33.4
Sydney,30.6,29,35.1,27.1,28.6,20.7,23.4,27.7,28.6,34.8,26.4,30.2

Comment: Just to clarify... Are you just sorting on the city names?

Comment: Yes, just on the city names.  

Also, is there any reason why the solution uses csv.reader() and not .readlines(), as I did?

Comment: IMO csv reader is unnecessary for this trivial case

Comment: Also worth mentioning that although your code is unnecessarily complex it does actually produce the correct results. No idea what your "homework interface" is but it's wrong if it tells you your output is incorrect. If the input data was different it could produce incorrect results because you're only sorting on the first letter of the city name. Thus if there were two (or more) cities with the same first initial letter, the results may be incorrect

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for testing and validating the code! I was losing it. Noted your comments on improving the code for more complex queries :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for additional modules in this case. Open the input file for reading (readonly) and the output file for writing.

Write the first line (column descriptions) from input to output. Then sort the list returned from readlines and write to output.

Like this:

```
ORIGINAL = 'original.csv'
NEW = 'new.csv'

with open(ORIGINAL) as original, open(NEW, 'w') as new:
    new.write(next(original))
    new.writelines(sorted(original.readlines(), key=lambda x: x.split(',')[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code on my machine and it works as it's supposed to. Is it possible to print out the CSV file from this homework interface before sorting?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. I have the original file in the homework interface and it looks correct :/